# Heap Corruption / Bad Alloc Issues Immediately in Main

Tags: c++, program-entry-point, heap-corruption

So i've been trying to solve my problems with this for a little while, and while I can't post any large amount of the source (NDA) I can post a small chunk and I'd like to get some input on what could cause this kind of issue right as the program starts.

```
int main(int aArgumentCount, char** aArguments)
{
    LZ_CHECK_MEMORY_QXL;
    LZ_CHECK_MEMORY_QXL;
    LZ_CHECK_MEMORY_QXL;
    LZ_CHECK_MEMORY_QXL;

    // ... Etc
}
```

All that define does is expand to a function that allocates an array of integers of size 150000000 and than deletes it immediately after..

However in the case of our application the first/second call of that allocation causes an immediate std::bad_alloc crash.

Does anyone have any pointers where I should be digging into to find this issue?

Comment: allocate less memory?

Answer (score 1):

`std::bad_alloc` means that the program could not allocate the memory you wanted it to allocate. 150000000 integers have - depending on your system and compiler - a size of 600 MiB or 1.2 GiB. Allocation of a single chunk of memory of that size might well be beyond the capabilities of your OS/system, so it is no wonder it fails. You will need to use another data structure than one single giant array.